# Como usar bootstrap para tamanhos de fontes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Gostaria de uma resposta didática sobre como usar Bootstrap para determinar tamanhos de fontes. Para ajudar, estou usando exatamente as seguintes medias-queries:

```
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {

}

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) {

}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) {

}
```

Pelo que eu entendi, deve-se dar um tamanho base para transformar `px` em `em` mas para continuar o meu trabalho e meu aprendizado, gostaria de ter certeza como usar isto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você disse, a medida `em` é uma medida relativa, ou seja, ela é calculada a partir de um valor fixo "base". Sendo assim, você poderia fazer o seguinte código:

```
/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    body{
        font-size:15px;
    }
}

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    body{
        font-size:25px;
    }
}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    body{
        font-size:50px;
    }
}
```

E toda vêz que você atribuisse a propriedade `font-size: [n]em` *(onde [n] pode ser qualquer valor `float` > 0)* para algum elemento, ele teria o tamanho da fonte de acordo com a media-query atual.

Exemplo: [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/dUZvs/)